# Link the I/O of one file to a tkinter window

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, chatbot

So I am trying to create a GUI for a chatbot that I have created and so far I have the chatbot finished, I have the GUI created and the entry field working to print to the text box.

Now I am hoping to link the user input from the Entry field to the input in my chatbot file, which will produce an output.  Then I would like to take that output and print it to the Text box on my tkinter window.  What would be the process to do that?

Here is my chatbotGUI.py file.  The chatbot is just called chatbot.py.

```
#Description: This is a chat bot GUI

#Import the library
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Military REACH Chat Bot")
root.geometry("600x800")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

main_menu = Menu(root)

# Create the submenu 
file_menu = Menu(root)

# Add commands to submenu
file_menu.add_command(label="New..")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As..")
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
#Add the rest of the menu options to the main menu
main_menu.add_command(label="Edit")
main_menu.add_command(label="Quit")
root.config(menu=main_menu)

messageWindow = Entry(root, bd=0, bg="white",width="30", font=("Arial", 16), foreground="black")
messageWindow.place(x=128, y=710, height=88, width=450)

chatWindow = Text(root, bd=1, bg="white",  width="550", height="100", font=("Arial", 16), foreground="black")
chatWindow.place(x=6,y=6, height=700, width=570)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=chatWindow.yview, cursor="arrow")
scrollbar.place(x=575,y=6, height=700)

def send(event):
    chatWindow.insert(INSERT, messageWindow.get()+"\n")
    messageWindow.delete(0, END)

Button= Button(root, text="Send",  width="12", height=3,
                    bd=0, bg="green", activebackground="green",foreground='#000000',font=("Arial", 12), command=send)
Button.place(x=6, y=710, height=88)
root.bind('<Return>', send)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried searching the internet for a solution, maybe I was overlooking some that were given, but I was unable to find one that seemed to fit my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here is my chatbot.py file.  I know printing probably isn't the best way to hold the output, so I can change that however needed.  I just had it working with print statements before working on the GUI

`

```
#Meet Reach: your friend

#import necessary libraries
import io
import random
import string # to process standard python strings
import warnings
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import chatbotGUI

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
nltk.download('popular', quiet=True) # for downloading packages

# uncomment the following only the first time
#nltk.download('punkt') # first-time use only
#nltk.download('wordnet') # first-time use only


#Reading in the corpus
with open('chatbot.txt','r', encoding='utf8', errors ='ignore') as fin:
    raw = fin.read().lower()

#TOkenisation
sent_tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)# converts to list of sentences 
word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)# converts to list of words

# Preprocessing
lemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
def LemTokens(tokens):
    return [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)
def LemNormalize(text):
    return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))


# Keyword Matching
GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up","hey", "whats up", "hi reach", "hello reach")
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hi there", "Hello"]

def greeting(sentence):
    """If user's input is a greeting, return a greeting response"""
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
            return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)


# Generating response
def response(user_response):
    reach_response=''
    sent_tokens.append(user_response)
    TfidfVec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
    tfidf = TfidfVec.fit_transform(sent_tokens)
    vals = cosine_similarity(tfidf[-1], tfidf)
    idx=vals.argsort()[0][-2]
    flat = vals.flatten()
    flat.sort()
    req_tfidf = flat[-2]
    
    if (user_response=="what is military reach?" or user_response=="what is military reach"):
        reach_response = "Military REACH is an organization that works to bridge the gap between military family research and practice."
        reach_response = reach_response + "\nOur goal is to make research more accessible for military families."
        reach_response = reach_response + "\n\nIs there anything else that I can help you with?"
        return reach_response
    elif (user_response=="how many documents does military reach have?" or user_response=="how many documents does military reach have"):
        reach_response = "Military REACH has a database of over 6,000 documents containing research summaries, reports, newsletters, and more!"
        reach_response = reach_response + "\n\nIs there anything else that I can help you with?"
        return reach_response
    elif(req_tfidf==0):
        reach_response=reach_response+"I'm not quite sure.  Let me look and get back to you!"
        return reach_response
    else:
        reach_response = reach_response+sent_tokens[idx]
        return reach_response


flag=True
print("\nREACH: Hello, my name is Reach. I will answer your questions about Military REACH. If you want to exit, type Bye!")
while(flag==True):
    user_response = input()
    user_response=user_response.lower()

    if(user_response!='bye'):
        if(user_response=='thanks' or user_response=='thank you' ):
            #flag = False
            print("\nREACH: You are welcome. Do you need anything else?")
            if (user_response == 'yes'):
                print("\nREACH: What else can I help you with?")
            else:
                flag = False
                print("\nREACH: Okay, bye then. Take care!")
        else:
            if(greeting(user_response)!=None):
                print("\nREACH: "+greeting(user_response))
            else:
                print("\nREACH: ",end="")
                print(response(user_response))
                sent_tokens.remove(user_response)
    else:
        flag=False
        print("\nREACH: Bye! Take care.")    
        

#interface = chatbotGUI()

#interface.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

First import your chatbot.py.

```
import chatbot
```

And I tweaked the 'send function a bit.

```
def send(event=None):
    if messageWindow.get() != "":
        chatWindow.insert(INSERT, "You : " + messageWindow.get()+"\n")
        chat_bot_response(messageWindow.get())
        messageWindow.delete(0, END)
```

Add chat_bot_response function.

```
def chat_bot_response(your_input):

    #chatbot do something, chatbot.py function, class......

    chat_bot_response = f"{your_input}. Do Something"
    chatWindow.insert(INSERT, "ChatBot : " + chat_bot_response + "\n")
```

Here, the chat_bot _response variable can be set to the result of the chatbot performing an action.

I haven't seen chatbot.py, so it's hard to give an exact answer.